# Problem with showing $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_A \cos(nxy) \, d\lambda_2=0$

Tags: integration, limits, functions, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I need to show that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int\limits_A \cos(nxy) \, d\lambda_2=0$$ for every Borel set $A\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ which has finite Lebesgue measure.

I tried to use the definition of Lebesgue measure, namely
$$ \int \chi_A \;\operatorname d\mu := \mu(A),   $$
but when I am trying to use this fact it is not occurring very helpful in my opinion. Is it a good idea to use Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem? Then the integrable function $g$ would be equal to one if I am thinking correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "We know that every $A\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ has finite Lebesgue measure." This cannot be true. Is this part of your assumption? I.e., are you examining the limit only for Borel subsets with finite Lebesgue measure?

Comment: Dominant convergence is irrelevant, since the function is bounded

Comment: In case $A$ has a finite Lebesgue measure, note that each slice $$A_y=\{x\in\mathbb{R}:(x,y)\in A\}$$ has finite measure for almost every $y$ and$$\int\mathbf{1}_A(x,y)\cos(nxy)\,\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y=\int\left(\int\mathbf{1}_{A_y}(x)\cos(nxy)\,\mathrm{d}x\right)\mathrm{d}y$$ by the Fubini's Theorem. Now use the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma and the dominated convergence theorem to conclude. Alternatively, one can adapt the standard proof of Riemann-Lebesgue lemma (using $L^1$-approximation by nice functions).

Comment: @Sangchul Lee *now use the Riemann-Lebesque lemma* - unfortunately I don't see what is the aim of using it and how to do this.

Comment: Riemann-Lebesgue lemma tells that $$\lim_{a\to\infty}\int f(x)\cos(ax)\,\mathrm{d}x=0$$ for any integrable $f$. In this case, if $y\neq0$ and $\operatorname{Leb}(A_y)<\infty$, then $\mathbf{1}_{A_y}$ is integrable and hence $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int\mathbf{1}_{A_y}(x)\cos((ny)x)\,\mathrm{d}x=0$$ by the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma. In other words,$$f_n(y):=\int\mathbf{1}_{A_y}(x)\cos(nxy)\,\mathrm{d}x$$ converges to $0$ pointwise a.e. as $n\to\infty$. Moreover, $|f_n(y)|\leq\operatorname{Leb}(A_y)$ shows that $f_n$ are dominated by the integrable function $y\mapsto\operatorname{Leb}(A_y)$.

Comment: @Sangchul Lee thank you very much. I have one more question - could you give me a link with Riemann-Lebesque lemma? In Wikipedia there is different version and I have found only version with $\sin(ax)$ instead of $\cos(ax)$.

Comment: Here is this link: http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-riemann-lebesgue-lemma

Comment: @Novice, You may check the corollary of the link. On the other hand, if you have never exposed to Riemann-Lebesgue lemma, perhaps it might be a better idea to solve your problem by following the proof of RL lemma.

Answer (score 1):

Here we present a solution that adapts the proof of Riemann-Lebesgue lemma.

**Step 1.** We first consider the case where $R = [a, b]\times[c, d]$ is a rectangle. Then by the Fubini-Tonelli theorem,

\begin{align*}
\int_{R} \cos(nxy)\,\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y
&= \int_{c}^{d} \left( \int_{a}^{b} \cos(nxy) \,\mathrm{d}x \right) \mathrm{d}y \\
&= \int_{c}^{d} (b\operatorname{sinc}(nby) - a\operatorname{sinc}(nay)) \mathrm{d}y,
\end{align*}

where $\operatorname{sinc}(x) = \frac{\sin x}{x}$ if $ x \neq 0$ and $\operatorname{sinc}(0) = 1$. Also note that

$$\lim_{|x| \to \infty} \operatorname{sinc}(kx)
= \mathbf{1}_{\{c=0\}}
= \begin{cases}
1, & \text{if } c = 0, \\
0, & \text{if } c \neq 0.
\end{cases} $$

So, letting $n\to\infty$ and applying the dominated convergence theorem (check that this is indeed applicable!), we have

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{R} \cos(nxy)\,\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y
&= \int_{c}^{d} \lim_{n\to\infty} (b\operatorname{sinc}(nby) - a\operatorname{sinc}(nay)) \mathrm{d}y \\
&= \int_{c}^{d} (b \mathbf{1}_{\{by=0\}} - a \mathbf{1}_{\{ay=0\}} ) \mathrm{d}y \\
&= 0.
\end{align*}

**Step 2.** Now let $A$ be an arbitrary Borel set of finite measure. Then for each $\epsilon > 0$, there exists finitely many rectangles $R_1,\dots,R_m$ such that

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \left| \mathbf{1}_A - \sum_{k=1}^{m} \mathbf{1}_{R_k} \right| \, \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y < \epsilon. $$

This gives

\begin{align*}
&\left| \int_{A} \cos(nxy)\,\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y \right| \\
&= \left| \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \cos(nxy) \mathbf{1}_A \,\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y \right| \\
&\leq \left| \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \cos(nxy) \left(\mathbf{1}_A - \sum_{k=1}^{m} \mathbf{1}_{R_k} \right) \,\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y \right| + \sum_{k=1}^{m} \left| \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \cos(nxy) \mathbf{1}_{R_k} \,\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y \right| \\
&\leq \epsilon + \sum_{k=1}^{m} \left| \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \cos(nxy) \mathbf{1}_{R_k} \,\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y \right|.
\end{align*}

So letting $\limsup$ as $n\to\infty$, the previous step tells that

$$ \limsup_{n\to\infty} \left| \int_{A} \cos(nxy)\,\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y \right| \leq \epsilon. $$

But since the left-hand side is independent of the choice of $\epsilon > 0$, we may let $\epsilon \downarrow 0$ to find that the limsup is zero, which in turn proves the desired claim.